# One way Isolation

Tags: society, evolution

There is a place that has a natural boundary that allows all animals and plants to enter that place but any animal that can't fly is unable to leave that place.  This place is large enough to have a human civilization and it does have a civilization.  The people living both at this place and outside it have not developed flying technology yet so like other none flying animals people from outside the place are able to get to the place but the natural boundary prevents them from leaving that place.  People outside this place cannot learn anything about this place without becoming trapped in this place because by the time they get close enough to learn anything about the people of this place they are passed the point of no return.

What effect would this have on the evolution of animals in this place and what effect would this have on the culture of the people living there?  Would the one way isolation have any impact on which culture becomes more advanced technologically?

Comment: Can technology cross the barrier? For example, could someone who enters be bringing a two-way radio and some way of recharging it? That would immediately change the "isolated" area's ability to at least exchange information with the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the technology of the isolated group will go down. Even during the bronze age there was dependency on [long-range trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_sources_and_trade_in_ancient_times), and without it tools cannot be replaced if they wear out.

The culture "in the trap" might retain memories of life "outside the trap", especially if fresh castaways arrive from time to time. Have they been cast out of the promised lands by an angry deity? Or are they in sanctuary/heaven, with occasional arrivals of worthy outsiders?

One idea would be a river running through canyon badlands. The canyon is a mile or two deep, with whitewaters that prevent up-river travel. It ends in a lake which drains through an *underground* river. One-way entry, no exit, a very limited area on the shore of the lake.

Adaptive radiation can be relatively fast, and humans "in the trap" could be involved in selective breeding due to their farming efforts.

Answer (score 2):

With a regular influx of fresh blood, there is no real reason that evolution would drive any rapid change.  Populations need to be isolated from each other for them to genetically diverge.

With this set-up, the outside world is isolated from this hidden valley, but the valley is ***not*** isolated from the outside world.

Culturally, I would think the outside world would end up more technologically advanced.  The larger outside world would have active cross pollination among a much larger population driving their advancement, while within the "trap", any incoming information is sporadic and accidental.

However, there is no reason, story wise, that you could not have some special resource or discovery within the trap that gave them an epiphany towards some specific advancement(s) not available to the outside world.